# How do I reference a DataRow element by name in a DataSet retrieved from SQL?

Tags: asp.net, dataset, datarow

So I am building some XML using a `XmlWriter` and a `DataSet` but when it comes time to loop through each `DataRow` in the `DataSet` I can't figure out how do reference like "userid" and such that come back from the stored procedure. In page code I see them doing it as `Eval("userid")` or whatever which I am using the same stored procedure, but I am using it in an ASHX now... see the 'WHAT GOES HERE??' in the code below...

```
DataSet getData;
getData = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Course_NewReportGet_Get_Sav", objPAra)

//COUNT NUMBER OF RESULTS FOR COUNT ATTRIBUTE (must add!)

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = ("    ");
using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("data.xml", settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("changes");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("clientname", foundCompany.CompanyName);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("clientid", foundCompany.Abbreviation);
    //writer... INSERT COUNT ATTRIBUTE

    foreach(DataRow dr in getData.Tables)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("change");
        writer.WriteStartElement("user");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("userid", dr... WHAT GOES HERE??;                    
    }                
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your foreach is wrong. You need to loop over `getData.Tables[0].Rows`. If there's more than 1 table, you need to loop over getData.Tables.

But, the answer is it's an indexed property. So, `dr["userId"]` will get you the value.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in getData.Tables[0].Rows) {
   / * blah, blah */
   writer.WriteAttributeString("userId", dr["userId"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [DataRow.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item.aspx) Property as shown below

```
dr["userid"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straightforward.  An integer column in your datarow (dr) would be accessed with:

```
int someVal = (int)dr["ColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner foreach is the issue.

Should be

```
if(getData.Tables.Count > 0){
   foreach(DataRow dr in getData.Tables[0].Rows){
      writer.WriteAttributeString("userid", dr["UserID"]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add an iteration level - you're currently iterating over Tables in your `foreach(DataRow dr in getData.Tables)`, the DataRow objects are one level below.